# COPY in Dockerfile works in docker but not in kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, gitlab-ci

I am trying to deploy a simple HTML file to Kubernetes and host it using Nginx as a test. I am running into issues when copying over my website files.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY ./public /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

When I build this image and run it using `docker run` the website loads fine and I see my index.html file located in my public directory. If I try to run this in a pod using `kubectl` the files don't get copied over. All I see when I go to my site is the default Nginx welcome page. I am not sure why this is the case. the cluster is hosted on AWS EKS so it's remote to all the files. This is the same as I build and host my docker image on GitLab.

The image builds without any errors and as I said works fine when run in vanilla docker. It's only when I move over to Kubernetes that I run into issues.

I've made the project public so you guys can see all the abstractions that I might have left out in my question.

https://gitlab.com/k8group/k8site

Any help is appreciated.

Best Regards,
Eddy.

Comment: There could be multiple things causing this however lets start with if you shell shh into that container do you see your html files in the location you specified? If not but you do see it locally it does not sound like you are pulling the same image into your cluster. If you do see it it could be multiple things, do you have load balancer setup somewhere maybe is the ingress setup correctly do you have service discovery working? In my case it was that the loadbalancers were pointing to nodes that were failing due to not pulling down the image this due to auth issues for private repo.

Comment: What I see when I open a shell is that on docker the file is there and on the pod, the file is the default file: [reference](https://i.imgur.com/1fKn81z.jpg). From the looks of it, the image that is pulled is the same image. Both of them report that the image was pulled from `registry.gitlab.com/k8group/k8site:master`. 

I tried to disable the cache in the ingress by adding this annotation to the ingress `ingress.kubernetes.io/cache-enable: "false"` but I am not sure if I am doing that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I know if is only this, but in the quick glance I can say the key value in your ingress template must be pointing to the service port, not to the pod container port. Check the right config below:

```
    kind: Service
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: k8site
    spec:
      selector:
        app: k8site
      ports:
        - port: 8080
          targetPort: 80
    ---
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
        ingress.kubernetes.io/cache-enable: "false"
      name: k8site-ingress
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: prod.pepefanclub.com
        http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: k8site
              servicePort: 8080 <--- this must be the service port, that is 8080
```

Comment: I did this but it still seems to be showing the same site. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like this was a case of the image not being pulled. I changed the commit tag from master to a hash and the site started working.

changing a variable in my ci pipeline from

`IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG`

to

`IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA`

thanks, @EugeneDW for pointing me in the correct direction.

Comment: No problem happy coding 

Comment: @IdecEddy how is any of these variables different?